# Optimization over unit vectors

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to optimize a certain nonlinear function over real or complex vectors with unit $L^2$ norm, i.e., I am trying to maximize a function $|f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)|^2$ subject to $\sum_i |x_i|^2 =1$. I am wondering if this goes by a special name or if it can be mapped to some well known (convex?) optimization problem, or if there are efficient numerical methods to deal with the optimization constraint.

Comment: The fact that $x$ is a unit vector isn't really helpful unless you have some information about $f$.  Say you don't restrict $x$ to the unit sphere, then replace $f(x)$ with $g(x)=f(x/|x|)$ and you're back to the original problem.

Comment: What do you know about $f$? Is it polynomial?

Comment: Hi --- Actually |f(x_1,...,x)_n)|^2 is a homogeneous polynomial of degree four.

Answer (score 1):

Without any information on $f(.)$ it's impossible to say something. However, I don't think you can find a way to write this problem in convex form: first you are maximizing a quadratic function of $f(.)$ and this is already a bad sign. Moreover the domain $\| x \| = 1$ is nonconvex. A trick that sometimes can be used to optimize over unitary vectors is to relax the constraint to $\| x \| \leq 1$, and then add to the cost function some monotonic function of the norm of $x$, in such a way that $x$ is pushed to the boundary of the unit circle. This however is very likely to be in contrast with the cost function you actually want to maximize...